# Duplicate class io.realm

Tags: android, kotlin, realm

Do I have to remove realm in order to use realm.kotlin ? I want to transition to realm.kotlin incrementally.

classpath:

```
 classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:10.3.1"
 classpath "io.realm.kotlin:gradle-plugin:0.3.1"
```

plugins:

```
 id 'realm-android'
 id 'io.realm.kotlin'
```

dependency:

```
 implementation 'io.realm.kotlin:library:0.3.1'
```

Compile time error:

```
 Duplicate class io.realm.BaseRealm found in modules jetified-library-debug-runtime
 (io.realm.kotlin:library-android-debug:0.3.1) 
 and jetified-realm-android-library-10.3.1-runtime 
 (io.realm:realm-android-library:10.3.1)

 Duplicate class io.realm.Realm found in modules jetified-library-debug-runtime 
 (io.realm.kotlin:library-android-debug:0.3.1) and jetified-realm-android-library-10.3.1-runtime
 (io.realm:realm-android-library:10.3.1)
 ...
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for that ? I am on the same problem now

Comment: Nope, I migrated part of the realm.db to Room

Comment: Unfortunately, both of them for me are from external library, one built by KMM and the other by Lokalize